# O botao1 mostrar seu conteudo1, como interagir com os outro? Botao 1 mostrar conteudo 1, botao 2 mostrar conteudo 2...Muito Obrigado!

Tags: javascript

```js
let botao1 = document.getElementById('botao1');
let imagemcentro = document.getElementById('imagemcentro');
let conteudo1 = document.getElementById('conteudo_1');

botao1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (imagemcentro) {
        imagemcentro.style.display = 'none';
        conteudo1.classList.add('aparecer');
    } else {
        imagemcentro.style.display = 'flex';
    }
});
```

```css
#imagemcentro {
    display: flex;
}

.conteudotodos {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.aparecer {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>sub</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="block1">
            <div class="barramento">
                <button id="botao1">Saiba mais</button>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="block2">
            <div class="barramento2">
                <button id="botao2">Saiba mais</button>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="block3">
            <div class="barramento3">
                <button id="botao3">Saiba mais</button>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <!-- Conteudo -->
        <div class="centro">
            <div id="imagemcentro">
                <h1>IMAGEM</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="conteudo_1" class="conteudotodos">
                <div class="texto">
                    <h1>Exemplo1</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="conteudo_2" class="conteudotodos">
                <div class="texto">
                    <h1>Exemplo2</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="conteudo_3" class="conteudotodos">
                <div class="texto">
                    <h1>Exemplo3</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="sub.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para estes casos em que determinados elementos precisam ter um mesmo comportamento mas mantendo uma distinção entre si, eu recomendo o uso do atributo [data](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

> [Atributos data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#data-*) nos permite armazenar informações extras em elementos
>   HTML padrões e semânticos, sem a necessidades de hacks como classList,
>   atributos fora do padrão, propriedades extras no DOM ou o método
>   depreciado setUserData.

---

Podemos atribuir um atributo `data` ao botão e definir um valor que "apontará" para a `div` relacionada, conforme o exemplo abaixo.

```
<button data-target="#div">Click</button>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Você pode definir qualquer nome após o hífen (`data-*`). Eu optei por `target` por trazer um significado de "alvo", ou seja, o elemento que queremos interagir ao clicar no botão.

---

Então o seu código pode ficar da seguinte forma:

```js
let botoes = document.querySelectorAll('button.mudar-conteudo'); // Buscar todo elemento "button" que tenha a classe "mudar-conteudo"
let imagemcentro = document.getElementById('imagemcentro');

for (let i = 0; i < botoes.length; i++) {
  botoes[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (imagemcentro) {
      const divID = this.dataset.target; // Obtendo o valor do atributo data-target
      const div = document.querySelector(divID);

      imagemcentro.style.display = 'none';
      div.classList.add('aparecer');
    } else {
      imagemcentro.style.display = 'flex';
    }

  });
}
```

```css
#imagemcentro {
  display: flex;
}

.conteudotodos {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.aparecer {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">
  <div class="barramento">
    <button class="mudar-conteudo" data-target="#conteudo_1">Saiba mais</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block2">
  <div class="barramento2">
    <button class="mudar-conteudo" data-target="#conteudo_2">Saiba mais</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block3">
  <div class="barramento3">
    <button class="mudar-conteudo" data-target="#conteudo_3">Saiba mais</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Conteudo -->

<div class="centro">
  <div id="imagemcentro">
    <h1>IMAGEM</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="conteudo_1" class="conteudotodos">
    <div class="texto">
      <h1>Exemplo1</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="conteudo_2" class="conteudotodos">
    <div class="texto">
      <h1>Exemplo2</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="conteudo_3" class="conteudotodos">
    <div class="texto">
      <h1>Exemplo3</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua explicação, vai me ajudar muito, só uma pergunta, quando o conteudo1 entra a imagem é substituída, para eu fazer em todos os conteudos e aparecer somente 1 conteudo, sempre substituindo o anterior, como poderia ser feito?

Comment: Você pode trocar a instrução `div.classList.add('aparecer');` para `div.classList.toggle('conteudotodos');`. A função `toggle` irá procurar na classe do elemento se existe algum valor compatível com o que foi informado, se estiver, ele remove, se não estiver, ele adiciona.

Comment: Muito obrigado!